# Will apple reject my iOS app if it has unused UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appstore-approval

Will apple reject my iOS app if it has unused `UIViewControllers`?

I have many `UIViewControllers` in the `Storyboard`. However there are few of them I am leaving for next releases as they need more testing,their functionality is implemented though.

So the question is can submit the app with these conditions?

**Note** the unused `UIViewControllers` are isolated from the used ones, So there are no `Segues` between unused `UIVC` and a used one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's review policies.

Comment: I was about to post it on apple.stackexchange.com however I found many question regarding [apple policies] on this website

Comment: Read the description of the [appstore-approval] tag.

Comment: as per apple review guildlines if any viewcontroller is empty the app will reject else if you add like "Coming Soon" also reject, so you need to put some details else remove the used viewcontroller , when you need add on that time ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Apple will NOT reject apps because of this.

I submitted tens of apps with unused UIViewControllers (but this is not an eulogy).